# Horizontal scroll in rich:panel to default right to left

Tags: xhtml, richfaces, scrollbar

I have a rich:panel with a style="overflow: scroll" tag inside. By default, the scroll slides left to right. I am constantly adding a new dataTable to a dataGrid with the click of a button and I want the user to always see the most recent one, and since I have it set up so that each dataTable is added as a column to the dataGrid, the most recent one will always be on the right side of the dataGrid. Is there a way I can default the scroll to go right to left? Or maybe creating the columns from right to left?

Here is the code for my panel:

```
<rich:panel id="PREV" rendered="#{yieldSearch.update}" style = "overflow: scroll">
            <rich:dataGrid id="PT" value="#{yieldSearch.storeYieldTest}"
                    var="_yield" columns="#{yieldSearch.columns}">
```

```
            </rich:dataGrid>
            </rich:panel>
```

and here is my button:

```
<h:commandButton id="NXT" value="Add New Store" rendered="#{yieldSearch.update}" action="#     {yieldSearch.newStore()}" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is little bit difficult to answer because you haven't provided any code sample.
However I think you can use `javascript` for this. I assume your `panel` structure is as below.

```
<rich:panel id="myPnl"........>
    <rich:dataGrid id="myGrid".............>
      .........
    </rich:dataGrid>
</rich:panel>
```

And I assume you add `dataTables` in to the `dataGrid` by clicking a `<a4j:commandButton>` and calling an `action`. If so add an `oncomplete` event to the `<a4j:commandButton>` as below.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Add new data table" reRender="myPnl" oncomplete="#{rich:element('myPnl')}.scrollLeft += #{rich:element('myGrid')}.offsetWidth;"/>
```

Comment: I originally had an h:button but I switched to a4j, and it worked like a charm. Thank you!